# How to update nexsus dependencies in package.json file for js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a small question on dependencies in package.json file.I am working on a js project and i have to update the dependencies.normally for updating the dependency we do `npm i --save app@1.0.1`
 but if the dependency is a nexsus link then how to update the dependency.

Please find below the structure

```
"dependencies": {
          "****/core-js": "https://********@nexus.****.com/nexus/repository/*********-js-1.0.20.tgz",
 }
```

The framework has multiple package.json files .This is the automation package.json within the development project.Development project has its own package.json which does not have automation dependencies.Please help.

Comment: As you use an url, I think, you should manually update this full url.
Find the tgz with newer version on nexus.***.com and paste it in dependency url

Comment: Thank you Evgeny Lukoyanov for the solution.I manually updated it but after saving, the node_modules are not getting updated to latest dependency mentioned in the url.i did yarn install,npm i --save app@1.0.1 but still its not downloading the latest.Do i need to run some command ?Please help

Comment: It will be really helpful if any one has any idea on the above issue